# Strip all the default classes in Wordpress navigation and replace with custom classes

Tags: wordpress, navigation

Im having problems using the `wp_nav_menu()` function to get a defined menu and remove the `ul` and `li` default classes and replace with entirely custom classes. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're fine. If you look at the source of wp_nav_menu, you see the list of arguments that it accepts:

```
$defaults = array(
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'item_spacing'    => 'preserve',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => '',
    'theme_location'  => '',
);
```

Given the explanation you provided, i think 'items_wrap' will solve your problem.

Comment: Yes but I want to also clear the li items too. items_wrap only covers the ul part (I think)